# Declare generic delegate that receiving with parameters and without parameters and add it to dictionary C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics, delegates

I have a dictionary in code like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate> BODictionary= new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

I want to add for dictionary many some types of signatures of functions but to declare only one generic delegate I try to do this code:

```
public class BOMock : BOBase
{
  //  private delegate int DelInt(int id);
  //  private delegate string DelString(string name);
    public delegate T Del<T>(T item);

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BOMock() : base()
    {

    }
    public BOMock(int id, string name) : base()
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public override long Init(IModule module, ref Dictionary<string, Delegate> BODictionary)
    {
        try
        {

            base.Init(module, ref BODictionary);

            BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getMockById), new Del<int>(getMockById));
            BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getMockByName), new Del<string>(getMockByName));
            **BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getAllMock), new Del<Action>(getAllMock)????);// is it possible?**
            BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getAllMock), new Del<Action>(getAllMock1));// is it possible?
            BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getAllMock), new Del<string>(getAllMock2));// is it possible?
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex.HResult;
        }
    }

    private int getMockById(int Id)
    {
        return Id;
    }
    private string getMockByName(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
    private void getAllMock()
    {

    }
    private void getAllMock1(string name)
    {

    }
    private string getAllMock2()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

how is it possible to declare one generic delegate that also returns parameters and does not return either gets parameters and does not get? ,

someone have any idea?

thanks

Comment: "how is it possible to declare one generic delegate that also returns parameters and does not return either gets parameters and does not get someone have any idea?" It´s hard to get your question, please use some punctuation.

Comment: No, that´s not possible, your third delegate has `Action` as generic argument, thus it has to return an `Action` as well as of your delegates declaration. You need another delegate returning nothing at all. Apart from this I´m interested what you do with the dictionary once filled. Can you show how you declared it and how you´re using it? I suppose your dictionary is something like `<string, Delegate>` where the value is not strongly-typed. Thus I can´t see any reason to even care about the generic arguments at all.

Comment: can you give me an example to declare another delegate that not return I had a code

Comment: `delegate void Del<T>(T item)` for example?

Comment: it is not working , see my adding code

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate is declared as *expecting*  an instance of `T` and *returning* one. So in case you provide an instance of `Action`, you have to *return* an `Action` as well. In order to have a delegate returning nothing at all use another delegate:

```
delegate void SecondDel<T>(T item);
```

or just an `Action<T> SecondDel` which is a shortcut for the former.

However even this won´t help you much when you put all your delegates into a single dictionary that only has `Delegate` as value. However `Delegate` isn´t strongly-typed, thus the following won´t work:

```
var del = BODictionary("myString");
int i = del(1);
var another del = BODictionary("MyString2");
string anotherDel("Hello World");
```

because the values in the dictionary are just `Delegate`. So even if you put in a `Func<int>` (which is another shortcut for `delegate T MyDel<T>()`) into the same dictionary with a `Func<string>`, you can´t expect the *compiler* to infer the right type for the expected key - which is a *runtime-information*. A dictionary has exactly *one single* type for all its values, not just one type for the first value and another type for the second.

In order to execute the delegates you need to call `DynamicInvoke`. However this will just rertun an `object`, which you have to cast to your actual type:

```
var del = BODictionary("myString");
int i = (int) del.DynamicInvoke(1);
var another del = BODictionary("MyString2");
string str = (string) anotherDel.DynamicInvoke("Hello World");
```

Comment: I want to declare another  delegates that you can put all my adding code in one dictionary can you give me an example for this?

Comment: You can´t put different delegates into a single dictionary and expect the compiler to infer the right type for you based on an arbitrary string - a *runtime-information*. You *have* to cast your `Delegate` to its actual type, which assumes you *know* that type at compile-time, which you certainly don´t know. Thus you can´t do much with that dictionary.

Comment: can I put diffrent type instead of Dictionary<string, Delegate>() that can get all kinds of signitures? , I must to use one dictionary and I want to use minimun declare delegates

Comment: @user3580768 You´re stuck on getting `object` out of your delegates, no matter how you declare your dictionary. See my last paragraph.

Comment: I understood what you mean: that I cant declare one delegate for all but  I want you to give me an example also to getAllMock2 function and getAllMock function for this it isnt working :( and another qustion : ' can not to return an Action object???

Comment: @user3580768 Working with a delegate returning nothing at all (`void`)  works the same. Just use `del.DynamicInvoke` but don´t assign its result to anything.

Comment: I didnt want you to say how to **take** the delegate  from dictionary I want you to say how should I add it to dictionary : delegate void SecondDel<T>(T item); only specific for getAllMock1 function but when i TRIED TO ADD : BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getAllMock), new SecondDel<string>(getAllMock1));// is it possible?
                BODictionary.Add(this.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(getAllMock), new Del<string>(getAllMock2));// is it possible? **IT IS NOT WORKING**